# VirtualWire send function

Tags: library, communication, softwareserial, virtualwire

I am a little confused on how exactly VirtualWire's "send" function works. After looking at the code, the process I gathered is the following.

1. In the Arduino IDE, call `vw_send()` with the right parameters.
2. Inside this method, it will start to encode the message and create the packet.
3. Then before the function returns, it calls `vw_tx_start()`.
4. Inside that function, it enables the transmitter hardware and sets the variable "vw_tx_enabled" equal to true. Then this function returns, followed by the immediate return of `vw_send()`. So there is no where in this flow where the message is actually being sent.

However, the actual transmission of the message happens inside `vw_Int_Handler()`. But this function is never called in `vw_send()` or `vw_tx_start()`. So the only way this could be happening is if there was some sort of multi-threading correct? Because by setting vw_tx_enabled to true, the transmission process would begin inside vw_Int_Handler.

Can someone explain/clarify this?

Moreover, this library uses digitalWrite to transmit the bits. Wouldn't it just be faster to toggle the bits at the registry level?

Lastly, in VirtualWire, they send a 36 bit preamble, I assume this is for synchorinzation purposes. So if I want to send 128 byte packet length, how much of a preamble should I use? I believe the reason for VirtualWire only transmitting 27 byte packet length is because the 36 bit preamble will only keep the data synchronized for that long. So is there a certain formula used to determine the preamble size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the actual transmission of the message happens inside vw_Int_Handler(). But this function is never called in vw_send() or vw_tx_start(). So the only way this could be happening is if there was some sort of multi-threading correct? Because by setting vw_tx_enabled to true, the transmission process would begin inside vw_Int_Handler.

The `vw_Int_Handler` function is called from the interrupt handler of one of the timer modules in the chip. Yes, you could say it was some form of multi-threading in that it happens interleaved with the main processing of your sketch.

> Moreover, this library uses digitalWrite to transmit the bits. Wouldn't it just be faster to toggle the bits at the registry level?

Yes it would, but it would be less portable.  VirtualWire has been written to work on a wide range of chips, and doing low-level port access would make the code about 1000x more complex, having to include special code for each and every chip it runs on.  Easier (though less efficient) to just use `digitalWrite()`.

> Lastly, in VirtualWire, they send a 36 bit preamble, I assume this is for synchorinzation purposes. So if I want to send 128 byte packet length, how much of a preamble should I use? I believe the reason for VirtualWire only transmitting 27 byte packet length is because the 36 bit preamble will only keep the data synchronized for that long. So is there a certain formula used to determine the preamble size?

VirtualWire uses a coding system called 4b/6b (actually a sub-set of [5b/6b coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding#5b.2F6b)). In that system it takes 6 *symbols* to transmit 4 *bits*. It is a way of encoding the clock into the signal in a reasonably efficient manner.

The encoding system means that there can never be 36 alternating 1/0 bits in a message. That unique stream is used as the synchronisation because it can't be confused with anything else.  From then on it's just data encoded as 4b/6b. The limit on how much data can be transmitted in one packet is a purely arbitrary value. Since this is a low-speed protocol to low-power devices it is expected that they will have limited RAM, and so limited space to receive data. So small packets are the default.

The numbers in use, incidentally, have been chosen because they fit into the 4b/6b coding scheme quite nicely.  For instance 36 symbols of preamble is equivalent to 24 bits of data. The packet size is 30 bytes, three bytes of which are used for control information (checksum, byte count, etc), leaving 27 bytes of actual payload.  30 bytes is 240 bits, which is, in 4b/6b, 360 symbols. 360 symbols could be packed cleanly into 45 bytes for simple transmission (pre-encoding from binary to 4b/6b before transmission).

Other values won't fit quite so neatly.